# how to plot line chart from pandas filtered movies data

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df.loc[df['title_year'].isin(years2.index)].groupby('title_year')['imdb_score'].mean()
```

I am trying to plot a line chart from this filtered conditions from movies_metadata.csv file.
The graph is supposed to look like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRMiC.png)

[image]

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: df.loc[df['title_year'].isin(years2.index)].groupby('title_year')['imdb_score'].mean()

Comment: not this for plotting graph what have you tried